# Relation between airespeed and pushing force

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid, air

I'd like to know how can I estimate the maximum speed that can be achieved by a
"portion of wind" accelerated upward from rest on the surface of
a place by pushing forces.

So far I've thinking in the relation between lift and speed (for an object such as an air plane),

$Lift=\frac{1}{2}ρv^2 × C_l × area$

But not sure if I can use this expression for "a portion of air", for air moving specifically.

Comment: when the power input is equal to the sum of the losses.

Comment: How is the air moved? What sort of forces are moving the air?

Comment: @SF. There's no info about that..only the one i give away.

Comment: @VANESSA: Unfortunately, in this case this is unanswerable because a "pushing force" may be anything. Blades of horizontal propeller; buoyancy as the air is heated; electrostatic repulsion after ionizing the air; the entire surface moving upwards; the air being enclosed in a balloon and pushed by kid's hands; explosives going off and displacing the air with combustion products. How can we give an equation without a clue what the input variables are?

Comment: I can think of three situations that would match the conditions in your questions: atmospheric thermals over land, cyclones/hurricanes or a near surface nuclear detonation.